# Trying to join 2 tables and SUM() time from dates

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to write an SQL query that will create a list of all the books that have been checked out in the past month, and how long each book has been checked out.

I have a `books` table...

```
library6=# SELECT * FROM books;
 isbn |                 title                 |    author     
------+---------------------------------------+---------------
  111 | Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone | JK Rowlings
  222 | The Art of the Deal                   | Trump
  333 | to catch a crook                      | Robert Muller
  444 | Im a cool guy                         | Forrest Stone
  555 | rich i am                             | Bill Gates
(5 rows)
```

and a `transactions` table with the records of when the books where checked out

```
library6=# SELECT * FROM transactions;
 id | checked_out_date | checked_in_date | user_id | isbn 
----+------------------+-----------------+---------+------
  1 | 2016-01-01       | 2016-02-01      |       1 |  111
  2 | 2016-02-02       | 2016-03-02      |       2 |  111
  3 | 2016-03-03       | 2016-05-03      |       3 |  111
  4 | 2017-12-06       |                 |       4 |  111
  5 | 2017-11-29       | 2017-12-04      |       5 |  555
  6 | 2017-11-28       | 2017-12-05      |       1 |  333
(6 rows)
```

A few of my nearer misses have been

```
library6=# SELECT DISTINCT  books.title, books.author  FROM books LEFT OUTER  JOIN transactions ON books.isbn = transactions.isbn ;
                 title                 |    author     
---------------------------------------+---------------
 Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone | JK Rowlings
 rich i am                             | Bill Gates
 The Art of the Deal                   | Trump
 Im a cool guy                         | Forrest Stone
 to catch a crook                      | Robert Muller
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Which database mysql or postgre? Also add your expected output

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you could use datediff() , sum() and group by

```
SELECT   b.title
      , b.author 
      , sum(DATEDIFF(t.checked_in_date , t.checked_out_date)) num_days
FROM books b  
LEFT  JOIN transactions t ON b.isbn = t.isbn 
group by  b.title, b.author
```

Answer (score 0):

For postgre:

```
select b.isbn, 
   b.title, 
   b.author,
   sum(DATE_PART('day', coalesce(t.checked_in_date, CURRENT_DATE), greatest(t.checked_out_date, CURRENT_DATE+ interval '-1 month'))) days_checked_out
  from books b
  join transactions t on b.isbn = t.isbn
 where t.checked_out_date between CURRENT_DATE+ interval '-1 month' and CURRENT_DATE
    or t.checked_in_date  between CURRENT_DATE+ interval '-1 month' and CURRENT_DATE
 group by b.isbn, 
   b.title, 
   b.author;
```

You can add left join and coalesce for SUM, if you need also to show books which were not checked out in past month.